# How to modify input value in function & return it?

Tags: matlab

I'm facing a question about using matlab to change a given variable inside a function & return it. This function should change the value w/o create any new var

according to the description, I suppose it is something like:

```
vec = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
func(vec);
vec
   1, 3, 5
```

after googling a lot, I've read a lot about that matlab is passing the reference rather than value. Thus the input parameter will be modified, and what I have to do is simply return it. NO luck...

Here is my code:

```
function x = func(x)
    x = x(mod(x, 2) == 1)
end
```

can anyone tell me why this is not working??

Comment: Looks fine to me. Were you perhaps expecting `vec` to be replaced?

Comment: TL;DR: you need to assign the output (cf. dup suggestion).  It's not working because Matlab's copy-on-write is not the same as pass-by-reference.  It is true that if the input variable is not altered, Matlab will not make a copy of it or if the JIT thinks it can, it will perform in-place updating. However, you cannot directly update the state of a simple variable via either of these mechanisms; that requires a `classdef` or a closure which possess their workspace in memory.

Comment: Thanks, the answer is very clear.